# What is this pipe component in my gas range connection?

Tags: gas

I need to replace gas supply line for my gas range. Please look at picture of my existing supply line connection.

Red arrow shows shuttoff valve.
What is blue part ? Is that kind of extension coupling ?
Where do I need to disconnect old line from ? From yellow nut ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The part in blue is just a nipple from the valve to a reducer for the corrugated pipe connection which is where you want to disconnect the line. Naturally, make sure your gas valve is in the off position, the handle perpendicular to the pipe.

Many jurisdictions do not allow homeowners to connect/disconnect gas appliances. Check with your gas company for compliance. they may come out and do it for free. They would also check the lines/valves for any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from the yellow nut. use a suitably sized spanner or an adjustable - make sure to close the valve first. I would avoid the use of pipe grips ( like long-handled pliers) as they can damage the nut. It is also sensible to hold the adaptor so it does not move or loosen when undoing the nut.

Blue part is just an extension & adaptor.

Comment: FYI, the system flagged this: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Of course I'll click "Looks OK", but another sentence or two and you'll keep the system happy, and not require that someone manually check your answer.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Perhaps the system is failing to evaluate and understand the content of the answer - is any part incorrect?

Comment: Nothing I can see, just that it's extremely concise, and that's triggering the system.

Comment: No part is incorrect, but it's a bit vague. Disconnect how? What specific pieces are the adapter?